# Output of 2D DFT in jTransforms

Tags: java, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to write a high/low pass image filter using jtransforms. Everything is working very nicely in the sense that I can transform an image using the `complexForward` method of the `FloatFFT_2D` class, and then come back to exactly the same picture using the `complexInverse` method. I'm using a `float[]` input rather than a `float[][]`.

However, to apply the filter I need to remove some of the frequency components in between these two stages. My problem is that I don't know what the output looks like, or in other words, where within the output array the different spatial frequencies are stored. Is `a[0]` the DC value, for example?

The documentation isn't particularly forthcoming on this, so I'd be grateful if anyone knew the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - the low frequency components are in the corners. So if you need the low frequency components to be at the centre, a java version of fftshift needs to be implemented as explained in the link below:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html